# Spark streaming events missing issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have two streams in the first stream the data will be registered into the table and second stream will be aggregated the data and second stream is depending on first stream, the data has to be continuously flowed to both the streams.But i could see some events are missing and data is not writing to the table but when i could be preview the data manually i am able to see the data.Here is the code what could be the reason could anyone help me on this?

```
df1.writeStream.queryName(
            f"registration"
        ).format("delta").foreachBatch(
            lambda dataframe, _: fun1(spark, dataframe)
        ).trigger(
            processingTime="1 seconds"
        ).outputMode(
            "update"
        ).option("checkpointLocation", f"/checkpoints/delta/registration/_checkpoints/").start()

        updated_df = fun2(spark, df_with_signals)





 df2.writeStream.queryName(f"update_vehicle_trip_{use_case}").format(
            "delta"
        ).foreachBatch(
            lambda dataframe, _: fun3(spark, dataframe)
        ).trigger(
            processingTime="2 seconds"
        ).outputMode(
            "complete"
        ).option("checkpointLocation", f"/checkpoints/delta/aggregation/_checkpoints/").start()




def fun3(self, spark, df):

        aggregated = aggregate(df,True)

        df4 = spark.sql(f"select * from table1")

        joined_dfs = join_on_vehicle_id( aggregated,df, "left_outer").drop(
            df.column1
        )

        df5 = add_column(joined_dfs)

        updated_df = merge(df5 )

        return updated_df



def aggregate(df, agg_by_window=False):
    group_by_attributes = ["column1", "column2", "column3"] + (
        [window("column4_timestamp", "2 seconds")] if agg_by_window else []
    )
    aggregations = [
        agg_max(column5).alias(column5)
        for column5 in names
        if column5 not in ['latitude', 'longitude']
    ]
    return (
        df.withWatermark("column4_timestamp", "5 minutes")
        .groupBy(*group_by_attributes)
        .agg(
            agg_max("column6").alias("column6"),
            agg_max("column7").alias("column7"),
            agg_max("column8").alias("column8"),
            agg_max("column9").alias("column9"),
            agg_max("column10").alias("column10"),
            *aggregations,
        )
    )
```

here func1 and func3 are just the merge statements with insert,update and delete ?